Can't find AVI Raw output on Blender (not on video editing)
I downloaded Blender up to date on a new pc (4.2.1 LTS) and I can't find the AVI Raw option when rendering. I saw some responses on other posts about going on Encoding > AVI, but I'm not using video rendering.

Help!
Regards

AVI Raw was removed since Blender 4.2
The reason why is pretty well sumarrized on Everything New in Blender 4.2 - CG Cookie:

The AVI RAW and AVI JPEG movie file output types have been removed, since they were the same quality as H264 but with larger file sizes and reading those files in Blender took a lot of effort to maintain.

You can make a lossless video using FFmpeg's H264 codec set to lossless:

That being said, video output is rarely the best thing to do when rendering (and even less so a lossless video output, that's a massive waste of disk space and performance);
I highly encourage reading this answer that explains the pros and cons of using video vs image output, and some quick advices on which formats or codecs to use for different scenarios.
